# Can we auto approve a merge request based on the modified files/directories?

Tags: gitlab

In self managed Gitlab EE, can we approve or deny merge requests based on what files/directories was modified ?

For Example, if userX modified the directoryX, the merge request is approved automatically, if he modify directoryY the MR is denied.

Thanks.